# Hashing or Encoding functions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have the following functions in a VB script:

```
Function DecryptSHA1(ByVal strOriginalString As String) As String
    If strOriginalString = "" Then Return ""

    Dim dEC_data() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(strOriginalString)
    Dim dEC_Str As String = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dEC_data)
    DecryptSHA1 = dEC_Str
End Function

Function EncryptSHA1(ByVal strOriginalString As String) As String
    If strOriginalString = "" Then Return ""

    Dim shaM As New SHA1Managed
    Convert.ToBase64String(shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strOriginalString)))
    Dim eNC_data() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strOriginalString)
    Dim eNC_str As String = Convert.ToBase64String(eNC_data)
    EncryptSHA1 = eNC_str
End Function
```

I don't code in VB but as much as I can see the functions have nothing to do with encrypting SHA1 but rater Base64 encoding and decoding. Am I wrong? The only thing that can make me think about hashing is the `Dim shaM As New SHA1Managed` line in the `EncryptSHA1()` function but the `DecryptSHA1()` function doesn't use it anymore. Are these simple Base64 encode/decode functions or more?

Comment: the principle of a Hash is that it can't be decrypted only compared. So since you have a decrypt function it can't be a proper hash.

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks

Comment: `shaM.ComputeHash(...)` does appear to be more than just B64 encoding.  The decryptor wont do much though.  And the code is VB.NET not VBScript which are 2 very different things

Comment: So the decrypt function is obsolete. However the encryption does use: ComputeHash wich does actually create a hash.

Comment: You say the decrypt function doesn't decrypt the output of the encrypt function?

Comment: Why dont you flip all the cards and tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: I found this in a VB.NET script and I just want to figure it out what it really does.

Comment: Well, that VB *code* will hash some text but since a hash is one way, the "decrypt" method cant/wont do anything with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing these functions do is converting to and from base64.
In the `EncryptSHA1` function there is some SHA1 hashing code, but it is not actually used.
So there is no hashing nor encryption going on which makes the functions quite confusing.